# designing large data app using django

Tags: django

I have a design task and would like expert opinion.
I want to store some data that looks like this:

id, username, pass, small_pdf_doc, very_large_file -> (binary 30GB)

I want to use python, but have freedom to choose:

- nosql db
- relational db
- store data in relational db except very_large_file and store that on a drive and map the file name to the db

I need the solution to be scalable. What do you think is the best solution?
I've done some investigation and I'm considering using mondodb or cassandra.

Do you think they are both going to be scalable? Would the queries slowdown over time?
Also, I read the mongodb doc and it says parallel writes are not supported but there is a lock.
If 2 parallel writes are requeste, will the db break, or fail the second one, or schedule to do both?

Lastly, isn't it better if I just store the large files with the file name that matches the id on the disk instead of putting them in the database? That makes it easier to backup and allows parallelism.

Comment: stick the very large file somewhere other than your DB, don't ever stuff very large files in the DB unless you absolutely have to.  Stick it on disk somewhere that gets backed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should separate the file storage and the database :

- For `id, username, pass` you should use a classic relationnal db as PostgreSql. there is no much data to store and it will scall well.
- For the `pdf_file` and the `binary data` you should use an external storage as [Amazon S3 bucket](http://aws.amazon.com/fr/s3/). Going this way will ensure you an ("infinite") scalability.

Some usefull links :

- [Django Storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) let django handle exernal storages.
- [Django direct S3 uplaod](https://github.com/bradleyg/django-s3direct) As your files will be very large the obvious solution is to directly upload files to the S3 storage backend. I didn't tested this app but it gives an example.

You can find alot more on google  by searching **"Django amazon S3 direct upload"**

Comment: Great. About the large file storage on s3, I forgot to say that I'm not allowed to use storage outside the company. Is there a way to make it scalable across local private company servers?

Comment: This is more a question for a sysadmin and this is why i use aws s3. A solution would be to deploy a personnal OpenStack, but this is something very difficult to build and to keep working and scalling across multiples servers... If your company has a skilled sysadmin you can go for it, if not you should totally consider going for S3, *it just works*...

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use a relational db for storing `id`, `username` and `pass` and put the large files to your filesystem or even better to something like amazon s3. That would scale well. In my opinion most of your data looks like typical relational data so I would go with it.